# unicode-math and physics's \vb command

Tags: unicode-math, physics

I can't get bold math with packages `unicode-math` and `physics`, here is mwe

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $ a, \vb*{a}, \symbfit{a} $ 
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

the second `a` didn't turn bold. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I found that in `physics` package, it defines `\vb` as

```latex
% Vector notation
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vectorbold{ s m }{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\boldsymbol{#2}}{\mathbf{#2}}} % Vector bold [star for Greek and italic Roman]
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vb{}{\vectorbold} % Shorthand for \vectorbold
```

so I can redefine the `\vectorbold` command like this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vectorbold{ s m }{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\symbfit{#2}}{\symbf{#2}}} % Vector bold [star for Greek and italic Roman]
\begin{document}
    $ a, \vb*{a}, \vb{a}, \symbfit{a} $ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or I can use `\symbfit` instead of `\boldsymbol` and `\symbf` instead of `\mathbf` to reach the demand

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\boldsymbol\symbfit
\let\mathbf\symbf
\begin{document}
    $ a, \vb*{a}, \vb{a}, \symbfit{a} $ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to know is there some bad influence in these two methods?

---

I found some bad influence for redefining `\mathbf` and `\boldsymbol`, When I use `\grad`=`\boldsymbol\nabla` in `physics` package. which should give an upright, bold, nabla symbol. However `\symbfit` makes it italic,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\boldsymbol\symbfit
\let\mathbf\symbf
\begin{document}
    $ \nabla, \grad, \symbf{\nabla} $ 
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

Comment: Just beat me to it. I would recommend using the more semantic markup.  It will also simplify re-using your source in PDFTeX if you ever need to.

Comment: @Davislor sorry, I'm not an english native speaker. I don't understand what you mean. Could you please explain it a little bit?  :(

Comment: Pardon. I mean, I personally prefer a command such as `\vectorsym` for two reasons. First, it makes it easier to change the style of your vectors if, for example, you want to use an arrow instead of a bold letter. Second, it makes it easier to change from `unicode-math` and `physics` to other packages, such as if you have to copy your equation into a document compiled with PDFTeX.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for your explaination, I understand what you mean now